# Getting size of terminal (TTY, Command Prompt) using Java

Tags: java, terminal

I am trying to fetch the size of terminal (TTY under Linux/MacOS, Windows Command Prompt) and here I'm relying on VT100 escape code (get cursor position) because I do not want to use an extra library like "Jline3" just because of gathering terminal info like rows and cols.

It prints out the correct terminal size, however, I face two small issues:

1. I am enforced to press the ENTER key which I am simulating using the `java.awt.Robot`
2. The output of cursor is printed out when I try to read the character sequences using `System.in` (already tried `Scanner`, `BufferedInputStream`, etc. .. same effect)

Here a minimal example:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TTYTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        // Prints out e.g. "^[[30;120R" (=30 rows, 120 cols)
        // 1) simulate cursor moving to row 999, col 999
        // 2) request for cursor position
        System.out.println("\033[999;999H\033[6n");

        // The rows / columns of TTY will be printed out
        // --> however, I have to simulate VK_ENTER as it awaits my ENTER input
        // new Robot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        // read the stdin "^[[30;120R" -> "30;120"
        final var sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (System.in.available() != -1) {
            char ch = (char) System.in.read();
            if (ch == 'R') break;
            if (Character.isDigit(ch) || ch == ';') sb.append(ch);
        }

        final var result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);

        final var rowsAndCols = result.split(";");
        System.out.println("Result (splitted): " + Arrays.toString(rowsAndCols));

        final var rows = Integer.valueOf(rowsAndCols[0]);
        final var cols = Integer.valueOf(rowsAndCols[1]);
        System.out.println("Rows: " + rows + ", Cols: " + cols);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

**QUESTION 1:** Is there a way to read the get cursor WITHOUT pressing the ENTER key (by user or by `Robot#keyPress` simulation)?

**QUESTION 2:** And it is possible WITHOUT echoing the cursor position?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: So...now you've learned that those crazy escape codes **do not** work on all Consoles. Keep looking, you'll eventually find the right ones but then they will only work on your console.